# Make interface for a function that doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

In the code below, I get an error when I try to setCountryToSearch() saying **Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Country | ((currVal: Country) => Country)'.**

I understand I get the error because searchCountry does not return anything. So how can I fix this? What changes can I make to the interface? I tried putting a return and I still had the same error.

Interface

```
export interface SearchCountryProp {
  searchCountry: (country: string) => void;
}
```

Function

```
 const [countryToSearch, setCountryToSearch] = useRecoilState(countryState);
 const searchCountry = (country: string) => {
    Rest.getCountry(country).then((returnedCountry) => {
      setCountryToSearch(returnedCountry);
    });
  };
```

Rest

```
import Axios from "axios";

const Rest = {
  async getCountry(nation: string) {
    Axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${nation}`).then(
      (response) => {
        const countryObject = {
          captial: response.data[0].capital,
          continent: response.data[0].continents,
        };
        console.log(countryObject);
        return countryObject;
      }
    );
  },
};

export default Rest;
```

Comment: Can we get a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: it seems to me that `Rest.getCountry` typings are incorrect. it returns `Promise<void>` while correct return type should be `Promise<Country>`

Comment: @andrei how should the syntax for that look? Where should I put Promise<Country>?

Comment: could you provide definition of `Rest.getCountry`?

Comment: @ andrei I just made an edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

you should just fix your getCountry function by returning the result of the call. here I've added `return` keyword in the right place

```
const Rest = {
  async getCountry(nation: string) {
    // return here
    return Axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${nation}`).then(
      (response) => {
        const countryObject = {
          captial: response.data[0].capital,
          continent: response.data[0].continents,
        };
        console.log(countryObject);
        return countryObject;
      }
    );
  },
};
```

Comment: I did that and now I got a different error when I hover over setCountryToSearch(returnedCountry) : Argument of type '{ captial: any; continent: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Country | ((currVal: Country) => Country)'.
  Type '{ captial: any; continent: any; }' is not assignable to type '(currVal: Country) => Country'.
    Type '{ captial: any; continent: any; }' provides no match for the signature '(currVal: Country): Country'.

Comment: could you provide Country type?